# How to use print statement in sybase stored procedure when calling the stored procedure from application

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am using powerbuilder with Sybase ASE database. I am calling a stored procedure while doing an update from my application but I am getting an error in the stored procedure. I want to put some print statements in the stored procedure to check what the error is. How can I see the output of this print statement? How can I log the stored procedure?

Thanks in advance
Sharmistha

Answer (score 0):

There is no log of these print statements and they are not considered part of the result set. They are in the same channel as the Sybase ASE error messages.

They should be returned to PowerBuilder, in the SQLCA, sqlerrortext is the field.

That's not how I used to debug stored procedures though. I found it easier to capture the parameters being passed to the stored procedure and use Sybase's ISQL command line tool, not the Java GUI, to see the error messages.

Comment: Thx for the reply. Let me try this out via isql

Answer (score 0):

You can use function which will return the status code. Add "ON EXCEPTION RESUME" clause inside function and return global variable @@error to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom error logging procedure to store data in a log table and read errors from it during or after execution.

Alternatively, you can try the PRINT statement inside the procedure to see if you can get the stdout output into PB.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I added some logs in powerbuilder instead to check for my problem.